# "the" or "one's" in an idiom?

Tags: idioms

I've been learning idioms related to body parts, when some like these struck me:

> 1  A lot of young vandals who go looking for trouble are not right **in the head**.
>
> 2 Can you do this calculation **in your head**?

The **in the head** in 1 denotes a not-so-correct moral code in "young vandals"'s mind.

The **in one's head** (as in "in your head") in 2 denotes doing something inside your mind instead of physical acts.

My question is, as a simple difference between "the" and "one's" in an idiom can cause such diversion in meanings, is there any clear sign to tell when to choose **the** and when using **one's** instead? Or are the idioms' choice of words like these just as random as its origin and spread?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To be "right (or not right) in **the** head" is almost a set expression. "Messed up in the head" also works, but in general I can't think of other adjectives that can be combined with "in **the** head" in this way.

"In **one's** head" is a prepositional phrase which constrains the action of the sentence to the realm of mental thought. You described it pretty much correctly. Some other example usages are:

> - I solved the problem **in** my head.
> - I have a song stuck **in** my head.
> - I can't get that idea **out of** my head.

Comment: So I guess there’s no rule? You will have to remember which is a prepositional phrase and which is a set expression, then?

Comment: I think so, yes. Sadly this is very often the case with English; for example, phrasal verbs! You just have to learn them. As a German language learner I can totally sympathize, although German has its own unique challenges.

Comment: By the way, "in **the** head" is also a prepositional phrase - it's just that its usage is limited to certain set expressions, while "in one's head" has broader usage. That's the bit that you "just have to learn" I think.